# Difference in emacs org-mode for bash/shell

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Among other parameters, the Emacs setup I'm using contains the instruction

```
(org-babel-do-load-languages
  'org-babel-load-languages
  '((emacs-lisp . t)
  (python . t)
  (shell . t)
  (ditaa . t)))
```

When using org-mode to document and deploy small snippets of code, I noticed the evaluation by `C-c C-c` works both for invoking the `sh` argument the manual explicitly mentions, e.g. for

```
  #+begin_src sh :exports both :results output
tree -d -L 1
  #+end_src
```

as well as an instruction with `bash` of

```
  #+begin_src bash :exports both :results output
tree -d -L 1
  #+end_src
```

The question: should I use only `sh` (for shell) to retain portability instead for `bash`?

Comment: You're also in luck, I just pushed this today. As far as I know, much of the shell functionality for babel wasn't documented previously. https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/languages/ob-doc-shell.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a general answer to your question. It's up to your personal circumstances and preferences. If these are snippets that you use on your own computer, or on systems where you can count on `bash` being present, then there's no reason not to use `bash`. If they need to be portable across systems that may or may not have bash, then of course you should stick to `sh`.

I don't think there's any additional considerations added to the decision by using Emacs/orgmode.